# C++ calls python to execute a time consuming function, but an exception raised

Tags: python, c++

Using python3.5 C APIs, in a C++ program, we try to execute a time consuming (about 4s) function (exposed by a python module). But unfortunately, we got an error.

After some trials, we found this error may caused by a thread race condition, someone suggest that we may call this python function in a separate thread, we tried as displayed in the following part, but not worked.

Here is the main code sample which shows the basic calling procedure:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    DCPyAlgoThread *thred = new DCPyAlgoThread;
    thred->start();
    while(1){}
    return 0;
}
```

And the following piece is the self defined thread code, `python.h` already included in `dcpyalgothread.h`:

```
#include "dcpyalgothread.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

DCPyAlgoThread::DCPyAlgoThread(){
}
void DCPyAlgoThread::run(){    
   Py_Initialize();        
   if(!Py_IsInitialized())        
   {            
     cout <<"error python"<<endl;
     return;        
   }        
   PyEval_InitThreads();
   PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");         
   PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.append('./')");
   PyObject* pModule = PyImport_ImportModule("prediction");        
   if(!pModule)
   {
      cout<<"module not found"<<endl;
      return;
   }
   PyObject* pFunHello = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, "GetResult");        
   if(!pFunHello) 
   {
      cout<<"get function error"<<endl;     
      return;
   }
   PyObject* ret = PyObject_CallObject(pFunHello, NULL);       
   if(ret == nullptr)       
   {           
      cout<<"calling error"<<endl;
   }       

   Py_Finalize();
}
```

From the above code, the output comes to:

```
calling error
Exception ignored in: <module 'threading' from 'D:\\anaconda\\Lib\\threading.py'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\anaconda\Lib\threading.py", line 1283, in _shutdown
assert tlock.locked()
SystemError: <built-in method locked of _thread.lock object at 0x00000000072E53A0> returned a result with an error set
```

this indicates `pModule`, `pFunHello` are not null, but `ret` is null.

If we comment `PyObject *ret=PyObject_CallObject(pFunHello, NULL);` or use a simple python function (you may define as `def Hello(): print(r'hello')` to replace the time consuming function `GetResult`, everything goes well, no error outputs.

Comment: DCPyAlgoThread inherits from a class that Qt provides ?, also provides a [MRE], for example the script code

Comment: I think you have enough reputation to know that it is an MRE and that the comments are not useful to share code, if you want help then edit your question and provide what you have been asked

Comment: That's right, a simple subclass of ```QThread``` with two public methods. ```DCPyAlgoThread()``` and ```void run() override```.

Comment: `while(1){}` is UB. Don't you have `join` method or similar instead?